# adding a matrix loop iterations matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, fibonacci

I've created a function `Cont_frac(n)` returns the nth element of a "continued fraction" and other `fib(n)` that returns the quocient between nth element of Fibonacci sequence and the n-1 element. I would want to program a loop that returns me a matrix with the values of my both functions and your respective difference between golden ratio.

I thought the following code but matlab says *In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.*

```
matrix=zeros(5,4);
phi=(1+sqrt(5))/2
    for i=1:5
       matrix(i)=[Cont_frac(i);fib(i);abs(Cont_frac(i)-phi);abs(fib(i)-phi)]
    end
```

Thank your for your help

Comment: Would you expect `a=1; a=2; a=3;` to create a vector? You need to index into your matrix using the loop variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a vector value to a scalar `matrix(i)`. You need to tell MATLAB explicitly that you want to store the RHS as vectors at the ith position.
So, the code should read as:

```
matrix=zeros(4,5); %This dimension was incorrect given what you wanted to achieve.
phi=(1+sqrt(5))/2
    for i=1:5
       matrix(:,i)=[Cont_frac(i);fib(i);abs(Cont_frac(i)-phi);abs(fib(i)-phi)] 
       %Notice the second index in the matrix
    end
```

Comment: Thank you! I also achieved inserting columns by separately , matrix(i,1); matrix(i,2) ...